# Powershell - external command's parameter not accepted

Tags: powershell, microsoft-distributed-file-system

This seems like a simple problem but I am unable to fix it:
Running command in shell returns result

```
C:\Windows\system32>dfsutil link "\\server.domain.com\DFSRootname\Sharename"

Link Name="Sharename" State="OK" Timeout="1800"
        Target="\\server1\sharename" State="ONLINE"  [Site: site1]
        Target="\\server2\sharename" State="OFFLINE"  [Site: site2]

Done processing this command.
```

Trying to do the same in powershell

```
PS>
$path = "\\server.domain.com\DFSRootname\Sharename"
$dfsutil = "dfsutil"
$option = "link"
PS C:\Windows\system32> Invoke-Expression "$dfsutil $option $path"

DFS Utility Version 5.2 (built on 5.2.3790.3959)
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Unrecognized option "ink"
```

Why does it complain about link option?

Comment: Why are you using `Invoke-Expression` which just evaluates PowerShell expressions? Did `dfsutil link $path` all by itself not work?

Comment: yes. It yields same error

Comment: Sorry, not sure what did you mean 'just evaluates'? Technet says 'The Invoke-Expression cmdlet provides one way to run a script from within Windows PowerShell':  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176880.aspx

Comment: `Invoke-Expression` invokes *PowerShell* expressions. SS64 puts it more simply: http://ss64.com/ps/invoke-expression.html. So there's no difference between `Invoke-Expression "dfsutil link $path"` and `dfsutil link $path`, except for maybe some quoting issues that could be created in the `Invoke-Expression` way if `$path` has spaces.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.I may have misunderstood you. From your first comment that had 'just evaluates' phrase it looked like Invoke-Expression does just that - only evaluates expression and does not executes the script. Hopefuly someone will come up with a solution soon.

Answer (score 2):

Try the call operator (e,g '&'):

```
& $dfsutil $option $path
```

or

```
& $dfsutil "$option" "$path"
```

Comment: Sorry Shay, both commands return same otuput  Unrecognized option "ink" :(

Comment: Seems like problem only happens on my Windows 7 PS3 install. Command works fine on Windows 2008 R2 host with PS2 it works fine

Comment: What's the output of: "$dfsutil $option $path"

Comment: same thing. My colleague confirmed that he has same issue with Windows 7 and PS3. This does not happen on w2k8 ps2...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like installation problem with my Windows 7 PS3 install. Command works fine on Windows 2008 R2 host with PS2